How to integrate PayPal in Next js with paypal webhook?
I want to integrate PayPal webhook with my next JS project. I have been stuck here for the last three days. order create and capture order is working. but handle approve API is not working. I am unable to find where that error. because I am using webhook for the first time. So, I don't have much idea about it. Can anyone help me?
component/Checkout.tsx:
"use client";

import { useToast } from "@/components/ui/use-toast";
import {
  FUNDING,
  PayPalButtons,
  PayPalScriptProvider,
} from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "../ui/button";

interface PromoCodes {
  [key: string]: string;
}

const Checkout = ({
  plan,
  amount,
  credits,
  buyerId,
}: {
  plan: string;
  amount: number;
  credits: number;
  buyerId: string;
}) => {
  const { toast } = useToast();
  const [promoCode, setPromoCode] = useState("");
  const [discountedAmount, setDiscountedAmount] = useState(amount);
  const [isPromoCodeValid, setIsPromoCodeValid] = useState(true);
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState("");

  const promoCodes: PromoCodes = {
    DISCOUNT25: "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ncp/payment/F6JZVGEAL5L6C",
    // Add more promo codes and corresponding checkout links here
  };

  const handlePromoCodeChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setPromoCode(e.target.value);
  };

  const applyPromoCode = () => {
    if (promoCodes[promoCode]) {
      setDiscountedAmount(amount * 0.75);
      setIsPromoCodeValid(true);
      toast({
        title: "Promo code applied!",
        description: "You received a 25% discount.",
        duration: 5000,
        className: "success-toast",
      });
    } else {
      setIsPromoCodeValid(false);
      toast({
        title: "Invalid promo code",
        description: "Please try a different code.",
        duration: 5000,
        className: "error-toast",
      });
    }
  };
  const [orderID, setOrderID] = useState(null);

  const handleApprove = async (orderID: any) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/api/webhooks/paypal", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ orderID, buyerId, credits }),
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      if (data.success) {
        alert("Payment successful and credits updated");
      } else {
        alert("Payment failed");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
      alert("An error occurred");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
        <h2 className="text-xl font-bold">{plan}</h2>
        <p className="text-lg">Credits: {credits}</p>
        <p className="text-lg">Price: ${discountedAmount.toFixed(2)}</p>
        {plan !== "Free" && (
          <>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter promo code"
              value={promoCode}
              onChange={handlePromoCodeChange}
              className={`border rounded p-2 ${
                isPromoCodeValid ? "" : "border-red-500"
              }`}
            />
            <Button
              onClick={applyPromoCode}
              className="w-full rounded bg-purple-600 text-white"
            >
              Apply Promo Code
            </Button>
            <PayPalScriptProvider
              options={{ clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID! }}
            >
              <PayPalButtons
                fundingSource={FUNDING.PAYPAL}
                createOrder={(data, actions) => {
                  return actions.order.create({
                    intent: "CAPTURE",
                    purchase_units: [
                      {
                        description: plan,
                        amount: {
                          currency_code: "USD",
                          value: discountedAmount.toFixed(2),
                        },
                        custom_id: JSON.stringify({ plan, credits, buyerId }),
                      },
                    ],
                  });
                }}
                onApprove={(data: any, actions: any) => {
                  return actions?.order?.capture()?.then((details: any) => {
                    handleApprove(data.orderID);
                  });
                }}
                onError={(err) => {
                  toast({
                    title: "Error",
                    description: "An error occurred during payment processing.",
                    duration: 5000,
                    className: "error-toast",
                  });
                }}
              />
            </PayPalScriptProvider>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Checkout;


here is the api/webhooks/paypal/route.ts:
import { updateCredits } from "@/lib/actions/user.actions";
import Transaction from "@/lib/database/models/transaction.model";
import { connectToDatabase } from "@/lib/database/mongoose";
import { handleError } from "@/lib/utils";
import crypto from "crypto";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

const webhookId = process.env.PAYPAL_WEBHOOK_ID!;
const paypalClientId = process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID!;
const paypalSecret = process.env.PAYPAL_SECRET!;

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    res.setHeader("Allow", "POST");
    res.status(405).end("Method Not Allowed");
    return;
  }

  // Extract PayPal headers
  const transmissionId = req.headers["paypal-transmission-id"] as string;
  const transmissionTime = req.headers["paypal-transmission-time"] as string;
  const certUrl = req.headers["paypal-cert-url"] as string;
  const authAlgo = req.headers["paypal-auth-algo"] as string;
  const transmissionSig = req.headers["paypal-transmission-sig"] as string;

  // Get the body and parse it
  const body = JSON.stringify(req.body);

  // Verify the webhook signature
  const expectedSignature = crypto
    .createHmac("sha256", webhookId)
    .update(
      transmissionId + "|" + transmissionTime + "|" + body + "|" + webhookId
    )
    .digest("hex");

  if (expectedSignature !== transmissionSig) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: "Invalid signature" });
    return;
  }

  const { event_type, resource } = req.body;

  try {
    if (event_type === "PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED") {
      const { id, amount, custom } = resource;
      const { plan, credits, buyerId } = JSON.parse(custom);

      await connectToDatabase();

      // Create a new transaction
      const newTransaction = await Transaction.create({
        createdAt: new Date(),
        paypalId: id,
        amount: parseFloat(amount.total),
        plan,
        credits,
        buyer: buyerId,
      });

      // Update the user's credits
      await updateCredits(buyerId, credits);

      res.status(200).json({ success: true });
    } else {
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Event type not handled" });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    handleError(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
}

user.action.ts file:
// USE CREDITS
export async function updateCredits(userId: string, creditFee: number) {
  try {
    await connectToDatabase();

    const updatedUserCredits = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      { clerkId: userId },
      { $inc: { creditBalance: creditFee } },
      { new: true }
    );

    if (!updatedUserCredits) throw new Error("User credits update failed");

    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(updatedUserCredits));
  } catch (error) {
    handleError(error);
  }
}

Here is credit page:
import { SignedIn, auth } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import Image from "next/image";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

import Checkout from "@/components/shared/Checkout";
import Header from "@/components/shared/Header";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"; // Ensure the Button component is imported
import { plans as creditPlans } from "@/constants"; // Renaming plans during import
import { getUserById } from "@/lib/actions/user.actions";

const Credits = async () => {
  const { userId } = auth();

  if (!userId) redirect("/sign-in");

  const user = await getUserById(userId);

  return (
    <>
      <Header
        title="Buy Credits"
        subtitle="Choose a credit package that suits your needs!"
      />

      <section>
        <ul className="credits-list">
          {creditPlans.map((plan) => (
            <li key={plan.name} className="credits-item">
              <div className="flex-center flex-col gap-3">
                <Image
                  src={plan.icon}
                  alt="credit icon"
                  width={50}
                  height={50}
                />
                <p className="p-20-semibold mt-2 text-purple-500">
                  {plan.name}
                </p>
                <p className="h1-semibold text-dark-600">${plan.price}</p>{" "}
                {/* Correct price display */}
                <p className="p-16-regular">{plan.credits} Credits</p>
              </div>

              {plan.name === "Free" ? (
                <Button variant="outline" className="credits-btn">
                  Free Consumable
                </Button>
              ) : (
                <SignedIn>
                  <Checkout
                    plan={plan.name}
                    amount={plan.price}
                    credits={plan.credits}
                    buyerId={user.clerkId}
                  />
                </SignedIn>
              )}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </section>
    </>
  );
};

export default Credits;

I want to update my user credit when user pay with paypal.
